# How can I access functions whose names have been shadowed?

Tags: swift

I'm creating a subclass of `NSDocument`. From within the methods of this class, I am unable to call the `print(_:String)` function that writes to stdout, because it is being shadowed by `NSDocument`'s `func print(withSettings: [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey : Any], showPrintPanel: Bool, delegate: Any?, didPrint: Selector?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)`.

I thought it might be possible to access `print` by prefixing it with its module name (or using something like `global::` in C#), but I was unable to figure out which module it belongs to. The documentation states that `print` is included in the *Swift Standard Library*.

How can I access the commonly used `print` function in this case, and shadowed functions in general?

Comment: "The documentation states that print is included in the Swift Standard Library" Yes, so its real name is `Swift.print`. — The same issue arises in connection with Combine framework, which also has a `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard output print function is part of the `Swift` framework. You can call it that way:

```
Swift.print("Hello, world!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is currently a bug as something similar happened. It was in `NSURLSession` where some of the datatask functions is inaccessible since it was being over shadowed by functions with the same name start but has different arguments. This is in Xcode 11 swift 5+.